# Выбор кроссплатформенного фреймворка для создания мобильных приложений

Tags: android, ios

У меня вопрос, хочу освоить разработку мобильных приложений под ios и android. Проблема в том, что учить java и swift дело хлопотное и трудное для меня. Я смотрю в сторону кроссплатформенных решений, у меня встал выбор между Qt, Xamarin и Flutter. Прошу подсказать, какой из них лучше подходит и какие костыли в них могут быть и вообще есть ли смысл в них или лучше использовать натив.

Comment: Единственно верного ответа нет. Если нужно качественно и долго и дорого - делают натив. Если быстро, дёшево и некачественно - кроссплатформу. В обоих случаях будут костыли. Если всё же кросплатформу, то, ИМХО Xamarin. Он, вроде, популярнее остальных, а значит больше готовых решений и костылей. Flutter же слишком молод и его корпорация зла делает. А для Qt надо, вроде, кресты учить. А это явно сложнее Java. Да и Qt, вроде, не изначально для мобилок сделан.

Comment: ясно спасибо за информацию

Comment: Ещё всё-таки есть ReactNative(написан Messager) - тоже ему не два дня отраду и многие компании сейчас вполне его используют. У Fluttera есть другой плюс, вроде как на нём можно писать под так званную Fuchsia(или как там пишется), и если опасения многих подтвердятся, то это так и останится, потому сейчас как бы в перспективе, ибо Андроид может уйти в небытие. А по поводу стоит изучать кроссплатформ или нет, то тут стоит подумать о задаче, если вы пишете калькулятор(не сложное приложение) то можно использовать, если же это проект средней сложности то только Native, тормоза, это не приятная вещь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если для вас хлопотно разобраться с Java или Swift, по которым тонны материалов на русском языке, то как вы собираетесь разбирать с фреймворками, по которым очень мало материалов на английском и почти нет на русском? Не говоря уже что некоторые проповедуют весьма нетривиальные подходы. Flutter, например, сугубо реактивный фреймворк, если вы не освоили даже императивное программирование, вам будет очень тяжело.

Не воспринимайте фреймворки как упрощение работы. Они призваны экономить время разработчика, а не снижать порог вхождения. Использовать что-то, принципов работы чего не осознаешь, очень неблагодарное дело.

Если ваше приложение коммерческая необходимость - обратитесь к профессиональным студиям, если для собственного использования или развития - выбирайте платформу которая вам больше подходит и осваивайте "натив".